# How to transfer C# data to Flash?

Tags: c#, flash

I want to make an continuous transfer between C# and Flash. By the way C# is connected with a timer device, the C# make the time elapse to string, so it would be running like 0.1, 0.2, and so on seconds with one decimal so it has to be as fast as tenth of a second (stable).

I haven't find a way to do it. Wifi or local network, both would be okay. Saving to a .txt file and opening it with Flash is not so good because of slow file reading.

I forgot - the transfer would be from one PC to another, or to a Mac.